# C++ user input will be recorded when usleep is used, is there a way to clear them the next time cin is used to input

Tags: c++, input

C++ user input will be recorded when usleep is used, is there a way to clear them the next time cin is used to input?
Many times, I want the user to see the text, I have turned off the echo so that the user can't see everything he typed, but when he next type is, everything before that will be typed, I Tried emptying the input stream, but that doesn't seem to be the problem, I'm new to c++.

Comment: Yes there is a way to do it. But not in standard C++, this is operating system-specific. But what kind of a C++ textbook gives something like this as a sample task? Since you say you're "new to C++" I presume that you're following a textbook or a study guide, of some sort. What is the topic of the current chapter you're on, which gives such an unusual programming task? These kinds of highly technical, operating system-specific details is something I'd expect to be involved with only after thoroughly mastering C++, after 5-7 years of learning it, and then delving into OS-specific niche domains.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't have any textbooks, I'm currently in the second year of junior high school, so I can't get other textbooks, C/C++, python and C# are all self-taught, I have watched the CS50 video, but only learned pointers, after I learned pointers I don't have much energy to learn FILE.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I want to try to make a word game, I am currently using an online editor, but the system I bring seems to be linux instead of windows, I try to use <windows.h> but it doesn't work I found this header file, I tried to use #include <unistd.h> and it works. If this operation is based on the system, I would like to try to see the code that completes it, and try to learn, even if I can't understand it now, but in the future It will be of great help to me.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I used to learn C language, and when I had a problem I would look it up on many websites and compare the solutions, and when the problem was solved, I could remember it because each lookup would take a lot of time.

Comment: I never spent much time looking stuff up in C. I reached over about 2 feet and pulled my copy of [K&R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) off the shelf. I also had a POSIX API guide in easy reach. Windows programming gave me a bit of trouble because you needed about 10 books for that... Mind you, the Internet was a bit iffy back in those days.

Comment: But seriously the big problem with the Internet is most of what you find on it is wrong. C++ is really picky so a little bit wrong stands out more than it would in many other languages.

Comment: Would my best time to study C++ be in college?

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/6vEtwaTD3

Comment: College... Depends. Admittedly Stack Overflow sees the problems more often than the successes, but it sure seems like schools aren't teaching C++ all that well. Maybe you're better off on your own with a good book, and maybe you'll get a good teacher at a school. Hard to say.

Comment: Looking over the code at the link, I think you would be better served by the ncurses library than the C++ Standard IO Streams. [I've linked to their page at Wikipedia so you can give it a look over before you dive too deep.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses). IO streams have to work the same on Windows as they do on an embedded micro controller with 4K RAM and a serial port, and that limits what you can do with them.

Comment: C is about 1/1000th the size of modern C++. You can theoretically pick up C using a do-it-yourself style. It's not a big language. Heck, I wrote a C compiler myself, in my college days. C++? Fughetabboutit. You can't learn C++ all by yourself, from Google searches and Youtube videos any more than you can do the same about building a Boeing 737.

Comment: That's the return of the (in)famous `fflush(stdin);`?